# Method of characterist PDE, transport equation with 3 variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Let $u=u(t,x,y)$. How can I use the method of the characteristis to solve the following transport equation:

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}-\frac{\sinh(t)}{x}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\cosh(t)}{y}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=\tan(t) $$

where
$$ u(0,x,y)=x^2-y^2+1.$$

I don't know to solve this PDE because there is 3 variable. Anyone can shed light on how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's basically the same process except you end up with one more equation in your system of simpler PDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}-\frac{\sinh(t)}{x}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\cosh(t)}{y}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=\tan(t) $$
Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{-x}{\sinh(t)}dx=\frac{-y}{\cosh(t)}dy=\frac{du}{\tan(t)}$$
First characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{-x}{\sinh(t)}dx$ :
$$x^2+2\cosh(t)=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{-y}{\cosh(t)}dy$ :
$$y^2+2\sinh(t)=c_2$$
Third characteristic equation from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{\tan(t)}$
$$u+\ln|\cos(t)|=c_3$$
General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1\:,\:c_2\:,\:c_3)=0$ with arbitrary function $\Phi$ of three variables :
$$\Phi\left(\left(x^2+2\cosh(t)\right)\:,\:\left(y^2+2\sinh(t)\right)\:,\:\left(u+\ln|\cos(t)|\right)\right)=0$$
Or equivalent $c_3=F(c_1\:,\:c_2)$ with arbitrary function $F$ of two variables :
$$ \left(u+\ln|\cos(t)|\right)=F\left(\left(x^2+2\cosh(t)\right)\:,\:\left(y^2+2\sinh(t)\right)\right)$$
General solution :
$$\boxed{u(t,x,y)=-\ln|\cos(t)|+F\left(\left(x^2+2\cosh(t)\right)\:,\:\left(y^2+2\sinh(t)\right)\right)}$$
INITIAL CONDITION : $u(0,x,y)=x^2-y^2+1$

$u(0,x,y)=-\ln|\cos(0)|+F\left(\left(x^2+2\cosh(0)\right)\:,\:\left(y^2+2\sinh(0)\right)\right)=F(x^2+2\:,\:y^2)$

$$u(0,x,y)=x^2-y^2+1=F(x^2+2\:,\:y^2)$$
Thus the function $F(X,Y)$ with $x^2=X-2$ and $y^2=Y$ must satisfy :
$$F(X,Y)=(X-2)-Y+1=X-Y-1$$
Now the function $F(X,Y)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x^2+2\cosh(t)$ and $Y=y^2+2\sinh(t)$.

$$u(t,x,y)=-\ln|\cos(t)|+x^2+2\cosh(t)-y^2-2\sinh(t)-1$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the initial condition.

Comment: Awesome solution, do you recommend any material to study the method of characteristics in more detail?

Comment: On the web the material is extensive. But it is not obvious to find the more convenient. Sorry I have no particular reference to recommend. For overview only : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics .